# With protractor, how can I determine the class of a parent element to see if it is disabled?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, protractor

Using Protractor, I'm struggling with the syntax for selecting the parent element of a found item.  We have a paginated list of records, and what I'd like to do is see if the right-arrow for that list is disabled. The trick though, is that the arrow gets **disabled by its parent** div element.

Here is the abbreviated markup.

```
<px-page-navigation id="myList" name="myList" page-number="vm.pageNumber" total-page-count="vm.totalPageCount" show-first-last-page="vm.showFirstLastPage" class="ng-isolate-scope">
    <div>
        <!-- Other pagination button markup omitted for clarity -->
        <div class="btn-group px-margin-top-xx-small px-margin-left-xx-small px-font-link-disabled" ng-class="vm.arrowFont(vm.pageNumber + 1)" ng-click="vm.setPage(vm.pageNumber + 1)">
            <!-- Find this "right arrow" element, then get the parent div and determine if it has a class of "px-font-link-disabled" -->
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right px-image-font bold"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</px-page-navigation>
```

I've been able to successfully grab this element and click it.

```
<i class="fa fa-chevron-right px-image-font bold"></i>
```

But after capturing that element, I need to examine the **parent** container div to determine if that div has a class of "px-font-link-disabled".  In cases where it's disabled, then the test will not click the right arrow.  Otherwise the right-arrow icon gets clicked.

These are a couple of attempts that I've made to find the parent element.

```
// Attempt A
function findNewInstrument(newInstrumentName: string) {
    element(by.linkText(newInstrumentName)).isPresent().then(function (exists) {
        if (exists === true) {
            console.log('found it');
            return element(by.linkText(newInstrumentName));
        } else {
            var RIGHT_ARROW = '#myList i.fa-chevron-right';

            // TODO: Is the right arrow enabled?
            element(by.css('#myList > i.fa-chevron-right: parent')).then(function (arrowContainer) {
                if (page.hasClass(arrowContainer, 'px-font-link-disabled')) {
                    // Paginated through all pages, and didn't find the instrument.
                } else {
                    // Instrument was not on this page. Click the right-arrow and look for it again.
                    element(by.css(RIGHT_ARROW)).getLocation().then(function (location) {
                        browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(' + location.x + ',' + location.y + ')').then(function () {
                            element(by.css(RIGHT_ARROW)).click();
                        });
                    });
                    findNewInstrument(newInstrumentName);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

// Attempt B
function findNewInstrument(newInstrumentName: string) {
    element(by.linkText(newInstrumentName)).isPresent().then(function (exists) {
        if (exists === true) {
            console.log('found it');
            return element(by.linkText(newInstrumentName));
        } else {
            // TODO: Is the right arrow enabled?
            var RIGHT_ARROW = '#myList i.fa-chevron-right';
            element(by.css(RIGHT_ARROW)).then(function (rightArrow) {
                var parentDiv = rightArrow[0].findElement(by.xpath('ancestor::div'));
                if (page.hasClass(parentDiv, 'px-font-link-disabled')) {
                    // The right arrow is disabled.
                } else {
                    // Click the right arrow, then inspect the grid again.
                    element(by.css(RIGHT_ARROW)).getLocation().then(function (location) {
                        browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(' + location.x + ',' + location.y + ')').then(function () {
                            element(by.css(RIGHT_ARROW)).click();
                        });
                    });
                    findNewInstrument(newInstrumentName);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

This hasClass function gets called by the above. This is in our base pageObject.

```
public hasClass(elm: protractor.ElementFinder, theClass: string) {
    return elm.getAttribute('class').then(function (classes) {
        return classes.split(' ').indexOf(theClass) !== -1;
    });
};
```

In both cases (attempts A and B) the error that appears is:

> TypeError: element(...).then is not a function

Once I've captured the right-arrow element, what syntax would I use to examine the classes of the parent div to determine if that div has the disabled class?  If there is a simpler approach than the path I'm pursuing, then I'd be open to that as well. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TypeError: element(...).then is not a function

You cannot resolve the `ElementFinder` with `then()` anymore - this was an intentional [breaking change in Protractor 2.0.0](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-2).

The following is how I would check the class of the parent `div` element:

```
var rightArrow = $('#myList i.fa-chevron-right');
var parentDiv = rightArrow.element(by.xpath('ancestor::div'));

expect(parentDiv).toHaveClass("px-font-link-disabled");
```

where `toHaveClass` is a *convenient custom matcher*:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    jasmine.addMatchers({
        toHaveClass: function() {
            return {
                compare: function(actual, expected) {
                    return {
                        pass: actual.getAttribute("class").then(function(classes) {
                            return classes.split(" ").indexOf(expected) !== -1;
                        })
                    };
                }
            };
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @alecxe. That fixed my finder. Now I've got another issue, but I'll put that in a different question.  I really appreciate your help.